# How to make this postgresql query to use composite index only ? Any Suggestion

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

**Query:**

```
with firstData as
(select rm.display_name as register, br.createdat, br.status, br.id as runid
from bad_run br 
inner join bad_master bm on bm.id = br.badmasterid
inner join regis_master rm on rm.id = bm.registerid
where rm.display_name in ('abc', 'pqr')
order by br.createdat desc limit 100)

select fi.runid,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action = 'Add'  and type = 'BANK') as add,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action = 'Modify' and type = 'BANK') as modify,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action = 'Delete' and type = 'BANK') as delete,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action is null and type = 'BANK') as pending,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND (status = 'FAILED' or status = 'Failed') and type = 'BANK') as fail
from firstData fi
```

**Index Details:**

```
 INDEX composite_1_idx ON public.bigTable USING btree (runid, action, type) WHERE (runid IS NOT NULL)

 INDEX composite_2_idx ON public.bigTable USING btree (runid, status, type) WHERE (runid IS NOT NULL)

 INDEX runid_idx ON public.bigTable USING btree (runid) WHERE (runid IS NOT NULL)
```

**Table Details:**

```
TABLE bigTable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    createdAt TIMESTAMPTZ,
    registerId BIGINT REFERENCES bank(id),
    status TEXT,
    runid BIGINT REFERENCES customer(id)
)
```

**Problem:**

```
It supposed to use index only scan for all scenario (Pending, Add, failed) 

It is only using index only scan for (delete, modify)   

portion of Query:
select fi.runid,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action = 'Add'  and type = 'BANK') as add,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action = 'Modify' and type = 'BANK') as modify,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action = 'Delete' and type = 'BANK') as delete,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND action is null and type = 'BANK') as pending,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM bigTable b 
            WHERE b.runid=fi.runid AND (status = 'FAILED' or status = 'Failed') and type = 'BANK') as fail
from firstData fi
```

**Execution Plan:**

```
Subquery Scan on fi  (cost=79.27..21812.52 rows=100 width=44) (actual time=3.117..111.762 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=79.27..79.52 rows=100 width=76) (actual time=2.119..2.194 rows=100 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=79.27..79.90 rows=250 width=76) (actual time=2.118..2.170 rows=100 loops=1)
              Sort Key: br.createdat DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 30kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.84..69.72 rows=250 width=76) (actual time=0.093..1.630 rows=2500 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (br.badmasterid = bm.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on bad_run br  (cost=0.00..55.00 rows=2500 width=20) (actual time=0.017..0.253 rows=2500 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=2.79..2.79 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.063..0.065 rows=40 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.27..2.79 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.045..0.058 rows=40 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (bm.registerid = rm.id)
                                ->  Seq Scan on bad_master bm  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=40 width=12) (actual time=0.009..0.012 rows=40 loops=1)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=1.25..1.25 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=20 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on regis_master rm  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.016 rows=20 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (display_name = ANY ('{abc,pqr}'::text[]))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=11549..11549.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=38.433..38.43 rows=1 loops=100)
          ->  Index Scan using runid_idx on bigTable b  (cost=0.56..11475.63 rows=29585 width=0) (actual time=0.008..24.212 rows=17888 loops=100)
                Index Cond: ((runid = fi.runid))
                Filter ((type='BANK'::text) AND (action'Add'::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 17428
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=19.86..19.87 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.120..0.120 rows=1 loops=100)
          ->  Index Only Scan using composite_1_idx on bigTable b_1  (cost=0.56..18.33 rows=612 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.081 rows=598 loops=100)
                Index Cond: ((runid = fi.runid) AND (action = 'Modify'::text) AND (type = 'BANK'::text))
                Heap Fetches: 0
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=19.61..19.62 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.122..0.122 rows=1 loops=100)
          ->  Index Only Scan using composite_1_idx on bigTable b_2  (cost=0.56..18.11 rows=602 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.082 rows=603 loops=100)
                Index Cond: ((runid = fi.runid) AND (action = 'Delete'::text) AND (type = 'BANK'::text))
                Heap Fetches: 0
  SubPlan 4
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=11549..11549.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=38.433..38.43 rows=1 loops=100)
          ->  Index Scan using runid_idx on bigTable b  (cost=0.56..11475.63 rows=29585 width=0) (actual time=0.008..24.212 rows=17888 loops=100)
                  Index Cond: ((runid = fi.runid))
                  Filter ((action is null)AND (type='BANK'::text) )
                  Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  SubPlan 5
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=11549..11549.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=38.433..38.43 rows=1 loops=100)
          ->  Index Scan using runid_idx on bigTable b_4  (cost=0.56..11475.63 rows=29585 width=0) (actual time=0.008..24.212 rows=17888 loops=100)
                Index Cond: ((runid = fi.runid))
                Filter: (type='BANK'::text) AND ((status = 'FAILED'::text) OR (status = 'Failed'::text)))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 12730
Planning Time: 2.223 ms
Execution Time: 12282.836 ms
```

Comment: I don't understand this question; there is too little text in it. Also, the execution plan is incomplete.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated the Execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subqueries in the `SELECT` list are what is expensive; they are executed for each result row.

Use the power of filtered aggregates:

```
SELECT fi.runid,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE action = 'Add' and type = 'BANK') AS add,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE action = 'Modify' and type = 'BANK') AS modify,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE action = 'Delete' and type = 'BANK') AS modify,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE status IN ('FAILED', 'Failed') and type = 'BANK') AS fail,
from firstData fi
   LEFT JOIN bigTable b ON b.runid=fi.runid;
```